# Ajax call using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a PHP server page returning data in JSON format like this:

```
<?php 
$data = array(
    (object)array(
        'title' => 'myfirstvalue',
        'value' => 'myfirsttext',
    ),
    (object)array(
        'title' => 'mysecondvalue',
        'value' => 'mysecondtext',
    ),
);

$json = json_encode($data);
echo $json; 
?>
```

Now I'd need to display the JSON title attribute using AngularJS. Taken from a tutorial I've adapted the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myapp">

  <div ng-controller="MyController" >
    <button ng-click="myData.doClick(item, $event)">Send AJAX Request</button>
    <br/>
    Data from server: {{myData.fromServer}}
  </div>

  <script>
    angular.module("myapp", [])
        .controller("MyController", function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.myData = {};
            $scope.myData.doClick = function(item, event) {

                var responsePromise = $http.get("http://localhost/myfunction.php");

                responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.myData.fromServer = data.title;
                });
                responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("AJAX failed!");
                });
            }


        } );
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

However nothing is displayed when I click on the button. Any idea where is the problem with this code ?
Thanks!

Comment: if you put `console.log(data)` in success callback, does it show that data was received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line

```
$scope.myData.fromServer = data.title;
```

isn't good. In general 'yes' but not in these piece of code. Why? You PHP code return:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        'title' => ...,
        'value' => ....
    ),
    [1] => array(
        'title' => ...,
        'value' => ....
    )
);
```

You don't have key 'title' there. You should use data[0].title to display results (key '0').

I preferring to use in these case UnderscoreJS (underscorejs.org). Method _.pluck(list, propertyName) seems for me to be good. Read more here - http://underscorejs.org/#pluck